# Get ssh remote command to terminate so that xargs with parallel option can continue

Tags: bash, ssh, xargs

I'm running a command similar to the following

```
getHosts | xargs -I{} -P3 -n1 ssh {} 'startServer; sleep 5; grep -m 1 "server up" <(tail -f log)'
```

The problem is that it seems like ssh hangs for a while sometimes even well after the server has come up. Is there any problem with this command that might cause it not to terminate so that parallel execution can continue? When I run the command in a remote shell, the check for the server coming up seems reliable and closes punctually when "server up" is written to the logs.

Comment: What happens if it takes more than five seconds for the server to come up? Perhaps the `grep` is getting an _old_ version of a log file, one that is never written to again?

Comment: Five seconds is empirically plenty long for them to be cleared and recreated.

Comment: If you want to guarantee it, you could just `rm -f log; startServer; touch log; tail -f log` (the touch will create the file if `startServer` didn't, so `tail` won't fail that the file doesn't exist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the remote command being

```
startServer; sleep 5; grep -m 1 "server up" <(tail -f log)
```

I'd use

```
grep -m 1 "server up" <(tail -F log -n 0) & startServer ; wait
```

Differences:

- Start tailing the log *before* attempting to restart the server, so that we don't miss any messages. We start at the end of the log so we don't see any previous "server up" messages.
- Use `tail`'s `-F` option instead of `-f`, so that if the log file is rotated we will follow the new file, instead of continuing to uselessly follow the old file.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways I could see it failing to terminate:

1. Remote end hangs on `startServer`
2. The server generates so many messages after "server up", `tail -f` doesn't catch that line and waits forever (since `tail` will, by default, take the last 10 lines)

`ssh` could also fail to connect for a variety of reasons: host down, keys lost, etc. I would add some error checking conditions in the form of writing to a log and/or having

```
|| echo "Failed to do stuff" | mail -s SUBJECT TO@WHO.com
```

Comment: True, but I thought the question was asking if there was a situation that would cause the command not to terminate. Agreed, this won't cause `ssh` to change behaviour in the slightest.